# How to use multiprocessing or pool to boost up the performance of ArcPy script

Tags: python, arcpy, parallel-processing

I created some arcpy script which actually runs slow on huge dataset. such as 100000 feature in it.
I read from below path that multiprocessing can boost up arcpy script script performance.
 http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/08/29/multiprocessing/
I tried it myself and applied it in my code.

It is giving an error "Could not find file: from multiprocessing.forking import main;main().mxd"

I could not understand what does this error means,
and was unable to get any reference or help from any Internet source about the error.

Below is the code which actually find duplicates in a neaby buffer area(defined by user input)

```
import arcpy
import os
import multiprocessing
# defining input
inputFeatureClass = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
InputField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Distance = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
#checking whether UNIID  and dup field exist or not, if not than adding it
to_add = ["UNIID","Dup"]
#Create a list of existing field names
fieldList = arcpy.ListFields(inputFeatureClass)  
fieldName = [f.name for f in fieldList]
for field in to_add:
  if not field in fieldName:
    arcpy.AddField_management(inputFeatureClass,"UNIID","TEXT")
    arcpy.AddField_management(inputFeatureClass,"Dup","SHORT")
#updating squence number into UNIID Field   
rows = arcpy.UpdateCursor(inputFeatureClass) 
counter = 1
for row in rows:
    row.UNIID = counter
    rows.updateRow(row)
    counter += 1

#setting up progressor
RowCount  = arcpy.GetCount_management(inputFeatureClass)
PACnt = int(RowCount.getOutput(0))
arcpy.SetProgressor("step", "Finding Duplicate...",0, PACnt, 1)

def Find_dup(oid_range):
  i = oid_range[0]
  j = oid_range[1]
  lyr = arcpy.management.MakeFeatureLayer(inputFeatureClass, 'layer{0}'.format(i),"OID >= {0} AND OID <= {1}".format(i, j))    
#selecting neaby Point for every point inside searchcursor
  with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(lyr, ["UNIID", InputField]) as cursor:  
    for row in cursor:  
        value=row[0] 

        field="UNIID"  
        exp=field + "='" +value+"'"  
        point_lyr=arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(lyr,"NEW_SELECTION",exp)  
        arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(point_lyr, overlap_type="WITHIN_A_DISTANCE", select_features=point_lyr, search_distance=Distance + " Meters", selection_type="NEW_SELECTION")  
#pushing selected points into array
        occursTwice = []
        cursor = arcpy.da.SearchCursor (lyr, [InputField])
        for row in cursor:
            occursTwice.append (row[0])
        del cursor
#counting occurance of every Field Value inside Array and updating into dup field
        cursor = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor (lyr, [InputField, 'Dup'])
        for row in cursor:
# check whether dup contains already a duplicate value, if yes than do not update lower value
            if occursTwice.count(row[0]) > row[1]:
              row[1] =  occursTwice.count(row[0])                          
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        del cursor
        del point_lyr
        arcpy.SetProgressorPosition()

def main():
  oid_ranges = [[0, 1000],[1001, 2000], [2001, 3000], [3001, 4000], [4001, 5000],[5001, 6000], [6001, 7000], [7001, 8000], [8001, 9000], [9001, 10001]]
  arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
  pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
  pool.map(Find_dup, oid_ranges)
  pool.close()
  pool.join()
if __name__ == '__main__':   
  main()


#Deleting UNIID Field and Unselect everything
arcpy.DeleteField_management(inputFeatureClass,"UNIID")
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(inputFeatureClass,"CLEAR_SELECTION")
arcpy.ResetProgressor()
```

Comment: I wrote a short document on geonet which describes how I turned a script that used multiprocessing into a script tool, it can be found [here](https://geonet.esri.com/docs/DOC-3824).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like this is a limitation of ArcMaps runtime environment. To quote *JScheirer* from ESRI, who further explains the issue in the thread [Arcpy Multiprocessor issues](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/31027):

"You'll need to run your script out of process (there's a checkbox in the script tool settings dialog) to get it to work. ArcMap sets up a runtime environment that may not be compatible with the way that multiprocessing bootstraps its runtime."